# Pickerview select row and didSelectRowAt functions

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uipickerview, uipicker

I am using picker view as a dropdown menu according to user's choice one of my text field needs to be disabled. I have added my delegate and in my didSelectRowAt function there is `textField.isEnabled = false` but when I tried to select row programmatically using  `myPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`. However when I use that function my didSelectRowAt function is not working and the text field that I need to disabled stays enabled. Why selectRow function is not triggering didSelectRowAt function and how can I trigger it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [didSelectRow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview) method programmatically like this.

```
self.pickerView(self.pickerView, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 0)
```